# Remove h1 tag wrapping Wordpress logo

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using a Ultimatum child's theme which wasn't developed or even chosen by me. I noticed that logo is wrapped in a `<h1>`. Of course, for SEO purposes, i need another, optimized one, and it looks like its presence is just disturbing.
I can't find it inside the theme, nor in the database. Not in the header.php file. Anyone got clues? Thank you.

Comment: No chance to solve this wirhout code one can only guess. It MUST be somewhere ;-)

Comment: Maybe, but grepping the whole directory did not get me to the right place; same for a search through all the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have something like this in your admin panel, notice "Tag for logo" property:
[image]

I got picture from here [Installing Ultimatum Theme Framework](http://cotswoldphoto.co.uk/installing-ultimatum-theme-framework/)

Comment: Yes i do. Thank you. Now i'll need to restore styles.